# param is not assigning values

Tags: apex, apex-param

param2 value null in doSomething method

```
public String param1 { get { return 'Welcome Message'; } }
    public String param2 { get; 
        set {
            param2 = value;
        } 
    }

    public PageReference doSomething() {
        return null;
    }

<apex:commandButton action="{!doSomething}" value="Click">
    <apex:param name="param2" value="{!param1}" assignTo="{!param2}"/>
</apex:commandButton>
```

Comment: It could be just a case of not seeing your actual code, but, as is, there doesn't appear to be a need for you to use `<apex:param>` here. If `param2` is simply holding the value of `param1`, then you can simply use `param1` in your logic instead of `param2`.

Comment: @DerekF I have just posted sample one from that code

Answer (score 2):

apex:param is working perfectly, problem is with command button rerender

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!doSomething}" value="Click" rerender="none">
        <apex:param name="param1" value="{!param1}" assignTo="{!param2}"/>
</apex:commandButton>
```